# Unable to pass props to child component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm still getting to grips with react but I can't see why this isn't working, it should be passing the props from `tabs` into `<Tab />` and outputting the button each time.

If I put no text next to `{this.props.content}` it doesn't display anything, if I put `testText` next to `{this.props.content}` it will output the button 5 times but only display `testText` not the `name` field it should be displaying via the `content={item.name}` prop

```
class TopCategories extends React.Component {

render() {
const Tab = () => (
  <TestBtn key={this.props.key} >
   testText {this.props.content}
  </TestBtn>
)

const items = [
  { id: 1, name: 'tab-1', text: 'text' },
  { id: 2, name: 'tab-2', text: 'text' },
  { id: 3, name: 'tab-3', text: 'text' },
  { id: 4, name: 'tab-4', text: 'text' },
  { id: 5, name: 'tab-5', text: 'text' },
]

const tabs = items.map(item =>
  <Tab key={item.id} content={item.name} />,
)

return (
  <Container>
    <Wrapper>
      {tabs}
    </Wrapper>
  </Container>
  )
 }
}


 export default TopCategories
```

Comment: you don't have `this` in `Tab` because it is a stateless function. `props` are passed as an argument instead: `const Tab = (props) => /*...*/`

Comment: I did also try that however my linter(airbnb) throws an error when using that syntax - unexpected parenthesis around single function argument having a body with no curly braces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass props to the stateless function and since it's a stateless component, this is not available. It should be something like:

```
const Tab = (props) => {
   return (
       <TestBtn key={props.key} >
           testText {props.content}
       </TestBtn>
   );
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the example however this throws an error in the airbnb linter which I'm not sure how to get around `unexpected parenthesis around single function argument having a body with no curly brace`

Comment: I edited my answer, I have not use airbnb linter before, hopefully the linter is happy this style

Comment: alternative would to have been to remove the () around `const Tab = (props) =>`

Comment: it also throws an error using curly brackets ' unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body', however as suggested by rlemon it works if the parenthesis around props is removed so many thanks for that answer!